# Salesforce - PDF generation with Arabic and English text

Tags: pdf, salesforce, arabic

I am trying to generate a PDF with both English and Arabic text. Please let me know if it can be done using salesforce and what should be the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce page or email template has `<apex:page renderAs="pdf">` attribute. Your safest choice of font will be "Arial Unicode MS", it's the only font with full unicode support. BUT it doesn't have bold variant so all your `<b>`, `<th>` etc will print with normal font weight.

If you need a different font / want to experiment - use this as base: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm

Apex has similar method to pull another page (standard SF page or Visualforce) as PDF. But it'll be server-side generation, JavaScript on that page will not run so forget about some pretty printing of say aura components. Back to basics, raw HTML / Visualforce. [`PageReference.getContentAsPDF()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_render_in_apex.htm)

If it's not acceptable to you - there are some JavaScript PDF generators, for example jspdf ([Git](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), [demos](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)) describes in Git readme how to integrate a custom font into it. These tend to be hit and miss, you'll have to experiment. And well, it'd be a JavaScript solution so then you'd need extra steps to save it to a file maybe or prompt download... And forget about making a VF email template with it, it'd have to be somehow saved to files/attachments first