# Visualforce Style issues when rendering as pdf

Tags: html, css, salesforce, visualforce

I need to display a legal document. Most of the text inside a p tag is normal; but the first word on every paragraph must be bold.
Font size, font family and text align work fine; it's just the strong tag that is not working:

```
    <apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="FiniquitosController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
      <head>
    <style>
        strong {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <p style="text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font: 10pt Arial Unicode MS;">
    <strong>PRIMERO.</strong> Rest of the text     
    </p>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Arial Unicode MS", is the only font with full unicode support in Visual force pdf engine, great for Arabic, Chinese/Japanese/Korean etc. BUT it doesn't have bold variant so all your `<b>, <th>, strong` etc will print with normal font weight.

If you need a different font / want to experiment - use this as base: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm

Check out my full answer, maybe the jspdf trick will be an option for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402680/313628

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I just changed the font to SansSerif, it looks decent and all my styles work fine :)